# set_weights for a layer issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting an error about set_weights but I can not fix it. I've added weight as uniform but it's not accepting it. I'm trying to make an ANN‌ with two hidden layers and a binary output level. the code is:

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3: 13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

#Encoding Categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
ct = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'), [1])],remainder='passthrough')
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories=[1])
X = ct.fit_transform(X)
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Part 2 - Kares
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Add input layer and first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=6, weights='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))

# Second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=6, weights='uniform', activation='relu'))

# Output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, weights='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "dense_1" with a weight list of length 7, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: uniform...
```

What's the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer`.

```
classifier.add(Dense(units=6, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
```

Or,

```
keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None)
```

To set weights for a layer, you have to use `set_weights` https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

Reference: https://keras.io/initializers/

https://keras.io/layers/core/

Answer (score 0):

See Keras documentation for [Core Layers](https://keras.io/layers/core/) to check properly usage. You're trying to set weights initializer for your layers. [Here](https://keras.io/initializers/) you can see keras default initializers.

Your code should be:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units=6, kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(), activation='relu', input_dim=11))
```